Formulating an MRF as a graph weights matrix
I have a binary Markov random field (MRF) of an image:
$$E \left( B \right) = \sum_{i, j} L_{i, j}^{0} + \sum_{i, j} L_{i, j}^{1} + \sum_{i, j} \sum_{m, n \in \mathcal{N} ( i, j )} C (B_{i, j} , B_{m, n})$$
Where

$B$ - Binary image where $B_{i, j} \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.
$L_{i, j}^{0}$ - The cost of assigning the value $0$ to the pixel at $i, j$.
$L_{i, j}^{1}$ - The cost of assigning the value $1$ to the pixel at $i, j$.
$C ( B_{i, j} , B_{m, n} )$ - The cost between pixels within their neighborhood.

I know $C$ holds the submodularity condition: $C(0, 1) + C(1, 0) - C(0, 0) - C(1, 1) \geq 0$.
How should one build a valid non-negative graph weights matrix given the above?
The motivation is using solvers which requires the weights matrix to calculate a cut.
For instance, using scipy's maximum_flow.
